# Calculate global distance between several locations

Tags: python, gps, coordinates, haversine

I am working on the calculation of the distance between two global positions based on their coordinates. When using only two locations, I get results:

```
def global_distance(location1, location2):
    lat1, lon1 = location1
    lat2, lon2 = location2
    radius = 6371 # radius of the Earth

    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c

    return d

lat1 = 55.32; lat2 = 54.276; long1 = -118.8634; long2 = -117.276


print( global_distance((lat1, long1), (lat2, long2)))
```

What if I want to calculate the distance between several locations? Assuming I have a CSV file containing three locations:

```
Location   Lat1      Long1      
 A         55.322    -117.17
 B         57.316    -117.456
 C         54.275    -116.567
```

How can I iterate over these two columns and produce distances between (A,B), (A,C) and (B,C)  ?

Comment: First, how are you reading that CSV in? A list of lists/tuples, dicts, or objects, a 2D numpy array, a pandas DataFrame, …?

Comment: I mean I want to read it as pandas dataframe and want to iterate over all three elements. But any way to read it is ok. I just do not know how to iterate correctly on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've read that CSV into some kind of sequence of sequences (e.g., `list(csv.reader(f))`), all you need to do is iterate over all combinations of locations. And that's exactly what [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) does:

```
>>> locs = [('A', 55.322, -117.17), ('B', 57.316, -117.456), ('C', 54.275, 116.567)]
>>> for (loc1, lat1, lon1), (loc2, lat2, lon2) in itertools.combinations(locs, 2):
...     print(loc1, loc2, global_distance((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)))
A B 222.42244003744995
A C 122.66829007875741
B C 342.67144769115316
```

While you're looking at the linked docs above, notice `combinations_with_replacement`, `permutations`, and `product`, which are often the answers to similar but slightly different problems.

This should be easy to adapt to a sequence of dicts, or a dict of `Location` instances, etc. If, on the other hand, you have something like a 2D numpy array or a pandas DataFrame, you may want to do something different. (Although from a quick search, it looks like just making an array out the `itertools` combinations with `fromiter` isn't significantly slower than anything else, even if you want to trade of space for time to broadcast your `global_distance` function.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd import the data from your file via pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep='\s+', index_col=0)
```

Additionally, you can import itertools:

```
import itertools as it
```

With this you can get all combinations of a iterable like this, as an example with the indices of the dataframe here:

```
for i in it.combinations(df.index, 2): print(i)
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('B', 'C')
```

This shows, that you'll get the combinations you want.
Now do the same with the data of your dataframe:

```
for i in it.combinations(df.values, 2): print(global_distance(i[0], i[1]))
222.4224400374507
122.66829007875636
342.671447691153
```

And if you want to have the location names included in the output, you can leave away the `index_col=0` when importing, so that A, B and C is also part of the `df.values` and you could write:

```
for i in it.combinations(df.values, 2): print(i[0][0], '-', i[1][0], global_distance(i[0][1:], i[1][1:]))
A - B 222.4224400374507
A - C 122.66829007875636
B - C 342.671447691153
```